# Visual Studio Scrum 1.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, scrum

I created a new team project with the Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 template. I'm trying to migrate my work items from the MSF Agile Template 5.0 to that one using the TFS Integration Tools/Platform.

I created the Work Item Type Mappings in the xml:

```
Bug > Bug 
Issue > Impediment    
User Story > Product Backlog Item   
Task > Task
```

I get many conflicts...but the relevant ones to this question are:

```
Details: Work Item Type 'Issue' is not mapped in the configuration   
Details: Work Item Type' User Story' is not mapped in the configuration
```

I created the configuration using the WorkItemTracking.xml template.

I'm using the following xml

```
    <SettingXml>
          <WITSessionCustomSetting>
              <Settings />
              <WorkItemTypes>
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="Bug" RightWorkItemTypeName="Bug" fieldMap="@@ALL@@" />
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="Task" RightWorkItemTypeName="Task" fieldMap="@@ALL@@" />
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="User Story" RightWorkItemTypeName="Product Backlog Item" fieldMap="@@ALL@@" />
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="Issue" RightWorkItemTypeName="Impediment" fieldMap="@@ALL@@" />
              </WorkItemTypes>
              <FieldMaps>
              </FieldMaps>
              <ValueMaps />
        </WITSessionCustomSetting>
  </SettingXml>
```

I've added rules to ignore the Target Field Does Not Exist conflicts.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like implicit mapping in TFS Integration Platform is really buggy. Added explicit field mappings and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your "left" and your "right" are switched?

Thanks,
Erin